# Ruby MySql2 query with DELETE

Tags: ruby, mysql2

I have new to SQL and everything works fine except when I use DELETE command:

```
  db = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "test", :password => "test")
  db.select_db('performdb')

  results = db.query("INSERT INTO perf (rowid, value) VALUES (46709394, 12345)")
  puts("After insert")
  results = db.query("SELECT * FROM perf WHERE rowid = 46709394")
  results.each do |row|
    puts("#{row[rowid]} / #{row[value]}")
  end
  results = db.query("DELETE FROM perf WHERE rowid = 46709394")
  puts("After delete")
  results = db.query("SELECT * FROM perf WHERE rowid = 46709394")
```

My code got an error after the DELETE query and exit.  Next line is never executed (does not see the "After delete").  INSERT and SELECT work fine, and I am wondering can I pass DELETE to query or there is another way to delete from DB using Mysql2

Thank you community

Comment: Do you get any errors? Lines don't just "not run".

Comment: @tadman the error said "Traceback (most recent call last):" and return back to original calling function.  The next line after DELETE does not get executed ...

Comment: That's a trace, not the error. Look above or below that text for the actual error.

Comment: @tadman finally I figured why ... I should not put `results =` there.  The correct way should be just `db.query("DELETE FROM perf WHERE rowid = 46709394")`  Thank you